# Why is the type of array created using array function a object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

When a array is created using the array function as shown below.

`Let array = Array(10);`

And console logging the `typeof array` it shows object but why ?

I saw this.

[image: proof image]

Comment: arrays are objects. You can type `Array.isArray(array)` in your console instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays are also type of objects.
If you want to identify if its array or not you can use `Array.isArray()`
if you check the data types array is not defined